# Why is my AI model trains but doesn't evolve - ML Agents

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, tensorboard, reinforcement-learning, ml-agent

Created a simple game in unity where ball should hit the targets without hitting the walls. So, started training and the results was too bad. The ball is just collecting one of the 4 targets. But EndEpisode() happens when it collects the last target.

[Screenshot of the scene and the balls path throughout the training of 1650,000 steps(if im not wrong, since I called it a generation for every 10,000 steps of training.)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQT95.png)

The ball doesn't even tries to hit the second target. What is wrong with my code?

I've even tried with RayPerceptionSensor3D replacing the sphere with a cylinder so that it doesn't roll over and disturb the rayperceptionSensor3d. But it gives even much worse results.

```
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Security;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.ComponentModel.Design.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using MLAgents;
using MLAgents.Sensors;
using TMPro;

public class MazeRoller : Agent
{

    Rigidbody rBody;
    Vector3 ballpos;
    void Start () {
        rBody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        ballpos = rBody.transform.position;
    }


    public TextMeshPro text;
    public TextMeshPro miss;
    public TextMeshPro hit;
    int count=0,c=0,h=0,m=0;

    int boxescollect=0;

    public Transform Target;
    public Transform st1;
    public Transform st2;
    public Transform st3;

    public override void OnEpisodeBegin()
    {
        rBody.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
        rBody.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        rBody.transform.position = ballpos;
        boxescollect=0;

        st1.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled = true;
        st1.GetComponent<Collider> ().enabled = true;

        st2.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled = true;
        st2.GetComponent<Collider> ().enabled = true;

        st3.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled = true;
        st3.GetComponent<Collider> ().enabled = true;
    }


    void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.name == "Target")
        {
            if(st1.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled==true || st2.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled==true || st3.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled==true)
            {
                SetReward(-3.0f+(float)(boxescollect));
            }

            SetReward(2.0f);

            h++;
            hit.SetText(h+"");

            EndEpisode();
        }

        else if(collision.gameObject.name == "Target1")
        {
            boxescollect++;
            AddReward(0.2f);
            st1.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled = false;
            st1.GetComponent<Collider> ().enabled = false;
        }

        else if(collision.gameObject.name == "Target2")
        {
            boxescollect++;
            AddReward(0.4f);
            st2.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled = false;
            st2.GetComponent<Collider> ().enabled = false;
        }

        else if(collision.gameObject.name == "Target3")
        {
            boxescollect++;
            AddReward(0.6f);
            st3.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled = false;
            st3.GetComponent<Collider> ().enabled = false;

        }

        //collision.gameObject.name == "wall1"||collision.gameObject.name == "wall2"||collision.gameObject.name == "wall3"||collision.gameObject.name == "wall4"||collision.gameObject.name == "wall5"||collision.gameObject.name == "wall6"||collision.gameObject.name == "wall7"

        else if(collision.gameObject.tag == "wall")
        {

            if(st1.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled==true || st2.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled==true || st3.GetComponent<Renderer> ().enabled==true)
            {
                AddReward(-3.0f+(float)(boxescollect));
            }

            SetReward(-1.0f);
            m++;
            miss.SetText(m+"");
            EndEpisode();
        }


    }

    public override void CollectObservations(VectorSensor sensor)
    {
        // Target and Agent positions
        sensor.AddObservation(Target.position);
        sensor.AddObservation(this.transform.position);

        sensor.AddObservation(boxescollect);
        sensor.AddObservation(boxescollect-3);

        sensor.AddObservation(st1.position);
        sensor.AddObservation(st2.position);
        sensor.AddObservation(st3.position);


        float dist = Vector3.Distance(Target.position,this.transform.position);
        //Distance between Agent and target
        sensor.AddObservation(dist);

        float d1 = Vector3.Distance(st1.position,this.transform.position);
        //Distance between Agent and target
        sensor.AddObservation(d1);


        float d2 = Vector3.Distance(st2.position,this.transform.position);
        //Distance between Agent and target
        sensor.AddObservation(d2);


        float d3 = Vector3.Distance(st3.position,this.transform.position);
        //Distance between Agent and target
        sensor.AddObservation(d3);

        // Agent velocity
        sensor.AddObservation(rBody.velocity.x);
        sensor.AddObservation(rBody.velocity.z);
    }

    public float speed = 10;
    public override void OnActionReceived(float[] vectorAction)
    {
        Vector3 controlSignal = Vector3.zero;
        controlSignal.x = vectorAction[0];
        controlSignal.z = vectorAction[1];
        //speed = vectorAction[2];
        rBody.AddForce(controlSignal * speed);
        //speed=0;

        count++;

        if(count==10000)
        {

            count=0;
            h=0;
            m=0;
            c++;
            miss.SetText(m+"");
            hit.SetText(h+"");
            text.SetText(c+"");
        }

    }

    public override float[] Heuristic()
    {
        var action = new float[2];
        action[0] = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        action[1] = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        return action;
    }
}
```

[weird Graph of the training - tensorboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VChi.png)
This is what I get after the training in tensorboard.

Comment: Have you tried playing the game as human? The plots lead me to think the environment is not working properly, possibly it's a fundamental bug or the rewards are not attributed correctly

Comment: yeah it works fine as human. I've even completed the course.

Comment: How can I make rewards more properly? Even I thought that it was due to the rewards. But don't know what should I change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are ending the episode with only one goal accomplished and not for the full accomplishment of your goal. So your chart looks messy, it's ending the episode too early, the agent doesn't understand its purpose.

I think you could add some new rules.
-if the agent recoils with his steps, he is punished
-the agent will receive a punishment if he does not take all 4 cubes before the end of the episode

the episode should end only if the agent completes the task of taking all 4 cubes (reward) or if the agent took a number of steps without achieving his goal (punished)

I hope that can help.
I feel my bad English.

**___edit 2:___**

It is very likely that your problem has similar characteristics to those described in this document. (specifically page 28)

https://repositorio.upct.es/bitstream/handle/10317/8094/tfg-san-est.pdf?sequence=1&isAllowed=y
(It is in Spanish, sorry, but google translator will give you a fairly accurate translation.)

The problem in the document is identical to yours, the agent had problems with the corners, when he reaches the corner he returns to the starting point, that only happened with the corners.

Have you tried changing the scenery?
Maybe ... try without the walls, to see if the agent is really looking for "all" the targets and go deeper into the problem.

the graph is the least of it, it is only a representation. You will not have a good graph if the agent is not fulfilling his mission.

Comment: Your english is good. I'm ending episode only if agent collects all the 4 targets or if the final cube is collected (or) colliding with the wall. So, I don't understand what changes to code should be done...

Comment: edit the post with the new answer, the sub comments are limited of characters.